# Angular with Auth0 - Why does loginWithRedirect() always return isAuthenticated$ as false?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, auth0

I posted this same problem on the [Auth0 Community Help Forum](https://community.auth0.com/c/help/6), but it has not gotten a response yet despite me posting it 2 weeks ago. Here is my post:

https://community.auth0.com/t/angular-loginwithredirect-not-working/98641

I am currently using `angular/cli 15.1.1` and `auth0/auth0-angular 2.0.1`.

In summary, if I try to execute `loginWithRedirect()`, it always returns `isAuthenticated$` as `false` even if I enter correct user credentials. Auth0 recognizes me as authenticated, but not the Angular API. `loginWithPopup()` returns `isAuthenticated$` as `true` when I enter correct credentials and call `handleRedirectCallback()`, but it is not as UI/UX-viable as `loginWithRedirect()`. I was wondering if I can get `loginWithRedirect()` to have `isAuthenticated$` to return `true` when I enter correct credentials.

I have posted more details below, pulled directly from my post linked above.

---

From [my community post](https://community.auth0.com/t/angular-loginwithredirect-not-working/98641):

Hello! I am having trouble with properly integrating Auth0 into my Angular application.

I followed [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular/interactive?_gl=1*1k6pr6m*rollup_ga*NzgzNjk2MjMuMTY2NTA3NTMwNQ..*rollup_ga_F1G3E656YZ*MTY3NTY1MDI0My4zNy4xLjE2NzU2NTEyMjEuNTkuMC4w&_ga=2.12680951.1571705136.1675650243-78369623.1665075305&_gac=1.50425179.1674590838.CjwKCAiAoL6eBhA3EiwAXDom5jDNyU58O-E_CXeIDhFqt23NGd9SqoljLLsl1NPYo81hOLJdowB_zBoC3IwQAvD_BwE) to integrate Auth0 into my Angular application, the one from the Auth0 docs. I made sure that I followed all of the instructions correctly.

Signing up for an account works, but after signing up, I cannot log in. When executing `loginWithRedirect()` after creating an account, it does not launch the login window. It instead takes me back to my app with `isAuthenticated$` set to false. When I look at the client authentication history, I see this:

[Auth0 login success responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzld4.png)

It says that I had a successful login, but the Identity Provider is N/A. Furthermore, when I look at the success details, Connection is also N/A and `connection_id` is blank. I do not know if this has anything to do with my problem.

I have looked through the Auth0 docs and searched on Google for answers as to why `isAuthenticated$` always returns `false` after calling `loginWithRedirect()`. I have noticed that many people have encountered and solved this problem with many different solutions, but none of those solutions fix my problem.

It is worth noting, however, that if I execute `loginWithPopup()` with specific checks that I found online beforehand, it authenticates fine with `isAuthenticated$` set to true. I provided my code at the end of this post with how `loginWithPopup()` successfully works for my app.

I do not understand why `loginWithRedirect()` always returns `isAuthenticated$` as false no matter what solutions I find online. I have provided my code below.

I am currently using `auth0/auth0-angular 2.0.1`.

`environment.ts` (I have `MY_DOMAIN`, `MY_CLIENTID` and `MY_AUDIENCE` filled in correctly in my app)

```typescript
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  auth0: {
    domain: 'MY_DOMAIN',
    clientId: 'MY_CLIENTID',
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    audience: 'MY_AUDIENCE'
  }
};
```

`app.module.ts`

```typescript
import { AuthModule } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { environment as env } from '../environments/environment';
// ...
@NgModule({
// ...
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: env.auth0.domain,
      clientId: env.auth0.clientId,
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: env.auth0.redirect_uri,
        audience: env.auth0.audience
      },
      cacheLocation: 'localstorage'
    }),
// ...
})
```

`login.component.html`

```html
<div class="container login-container">

  <div class="row">
    <h1 align="center">
      TITLE
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <button mat-flat-button
            class="login-button"
            type="button"
            (click)="attemptLogin()">
      Login or Sign Up (Auth0)
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <button mat-flat-button
            class="login-button"
            type="button"
            (click)="logout()">
      Logout
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

`login.component.ts` (note that `logout()` works)

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService, User } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { OnlineStatusService, OnlineStatusType } from 'ngx-online-status';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private onlineStatusService: OnlineStatusService,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) public document: Document
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.user$.subscribe((value: User | null | undefined) => {
      console.log("User:", value);
    });

    this.auth.isAuthenticated$.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
      console.log("Authd:", value);
    });
  }

  // attempt to login with the entered credentials
  // solution from https://community.auth0.com/t/isauthenticated-is-always-false/84794/3
  attemptLogin(): void {
    this.auth.isAuthenticated$.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
      if (!value) {
        let query: string = window.location.search;
        let shouldParseResult: boolean = query.includes("code=") && query.includes("state=");
        if (shouldParseResult) {
          try {
            this.auth.handleRedirectCallback().subscribe((value) => {
              console.log("Logged in!", value);
            });
          } catch (err: unknown) {
            console.log("Error parsing redirect:", err);
          }
          window.history.replaceState({}, this.document.title, "/");
        }
        else {
          this.auth.loginWithRedirect().subscribe((value: void) => {
            console.log("Logging in...", value);
          });
        }
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }
    });
  }

  // log out of account and go back to login screen
  logout(): void {
    if (this.onlineStatusService.getStatus() === OnlineStatusType.OFFLINE) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return;
    }
    this.auth.logout({
      logoutParams: {
        returnTo: this.document.location.origin
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the reason why it always returns `false`.

It never goes back to retrieve fresh data once it's been loaded the first time before the login.

The reason why it doesn't is the following line inside of `AuthState`

```
  readonly isAuthenticated$ = this.isAuthenticatedTrigger$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    shareReplay(1) // <------ THIS ONE
  );
```

I have created the following bug : [link](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/issues/447).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up going with a different authentication method in the end but thank you for addressing the problem!